# "a"+'b'+"c",What does two double quotes and one single quote combination mean in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For example
`SELECT "hello"'jacky'"hi" as value from dual;`
the result is `hellojackyhi`
But it confuse me that the use of this pattern `"a"+'b'+"c"`.
What does this pattern exactly mean?It's a use of double quotes and single quote, is it mean I can always combine 3 string using this pattern `"a"+'b'+"c"`?

Comment: There is no significant difference between the quotation styles in this instance

Comment: @Strawberry But why `SELECT "hello""jacky""hi" ` return a different resutl with `hello"jacky"hi`

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has a "feature" where it concatenates strings that are adjacent (and separated by a space):

```
select 'a' 'b' 'c'
---> abc
```

This works for both single quotes and double quotes.  Of course, double quotes might also be a column name.

So, this is a short-cut for string concatenation.  I strongly recommend that you use `CONCAT()` instead, so the intention is clear.

Comment: I try `SELECT 'a''b''c' as value from dual;` without the space in `'a' 'b' 'c'`,the result is `a'b'c`,and the example of mine is without space too, so i think it's a different use from my example `"a"+'b'+"c"`

Comment: And why there is a different between `SELECT 'a''b''c'` and `SELECT 'a' 'b' 'c'`?

Comment: With a white-space between, it means concatenation. (ANSI SQL compliant).

Comment: With doubled single quotes within a string, it means one single quote - escaped.

Comment: @jarlh If `With doubled single quotes within a string, it means one single quote  - escaped`,
 then `SELECT "hello"'jacky'"hi"` means `SELECT "hello'jacky'hi"`, but `SELECT "hello'jacky'hi"` returns a different resut with `hello'jacky'hi`

Comment: @jacky, I don't know how MySQL works when mixing single and double quotes.

Comment: @jarlh . . . The first quote is used to delimit the identifier/string.  If the other quote is inside it, then it is just another character in the string.